# How to cache module in CI with HMVC

Tags: codeigniter, caching, codeigniter-2, hmvc

CI (2.1.3) & HMVC (5.4)

I have tag cloud (/application/modules/tags)

This module displayed in the template as a block — Modules::run('tags')

If I use $this->output->cache(60) in controller, it cache all page (not tag cloud view).

How can I use blocks caching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do it with Codeigniters built in caching, it only allows you to cache full pages. You need to go and get yourself phil sturgeons partial caching library. https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-cache, this will let you cache whatever you want.

The only downside is that if your not careful, it can be a bit of a pain to maintain as the site grows, so think carefully about when you are going to need to clear various caches.